# How to concat a list of numpy array to tensorflow 2.0tensor for training

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a list of numpy arrays, the shape is `[1,x, x, 3]`. Here, `x` is different for each array. How to stack them into a minibatch to let keras model `output=model(stack_list_array)`.

For training, the Tensorflow version is 2.4, I already tried numpy stack or tensorflow stack or tf.convert_to_tensor directly for hours.

Something like

> a =np.ones((1,25,25,3)) aa =tf.convert_to_tensor (a, dtype=tf.float32)
> c =np.ones((1,25,25,3))*2
>
> cc = tf.convert_to_tensor (c, dtype=tf.float32)
>
> b =np.ones((1,25,25,3))*3
>
> bb =tf.convert_to_tensor (b, dtype=tf.float32) d =[aa, bb, cc] e
> =tf.stack(d, axis=0)

It works but
Under the real environment
It shows
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 7186, in raise_from_not_ok_status

Raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None #pylint:disable= protected-access
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:Shapes of all inputs must match :values[0].shape=[1,34,34,3]!=values[2].shape=[1,25,25,3][Op:Pack] name:stack

Environment  is tensorflow 2.4 python3.7
Please help me

Comment: Please add details of your trial and error code.

Comment: @M.Innat is it enough?

Comment: I think you need to look at the ragged tensor. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor